# Add/remove sprockets on cassette to customize gear ratios

Tags: shimano, cassette

I have a Shimano 105 10-speed cassette on my road bike, with sprockets 11-12-13-14-15-17-...-28 (I don't know by heart what comes between 17 and 28). I'd like to remove the 11, and put a 16 between the 15 and the 17 (because I dislike the gap between 15 and 17, and I don't use the 11 very much). I can find the sprocket: this one is for Ultegra, but I suppose it should work for my 105 too (http://www.rosebikes.nl/artikel/shimano-ultegra-cs-6600-10-speed-tandwiel-met-16-tanden/aid:119171).

Can I just take 11-15 off, put 16 on, then put 12-15 back on? Or is there something else I need to consider?

Alternatively I'm willing to buy another cassette instead, but I don't want to give up the 28. Are there compatible 10-speed cassettes available with 12-13-14-15-16-17-...-28 (or possibly even 29 or 30)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I replace only the smallest cog on my rear cassette?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/25289/can-i-replace-only-the-smallest-cog-on-my-rear-cassette)

Comment: If you don't find a Shimano then a SRAM will do because they are both compatible. But it will be hard to find one including a 16 tooth cog.

Comment: "Can I just take 11-15 off, put 16 on, then put 12-15 back on?" If the spaces between the cogs remain the same, there should be no problem. And if the cassette comes apart as some are riveted. (In the beginning they were held together by screws.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you want sram cassette** (which should be compatible):
Sram PG1050 and PG1070 come in a 12-28 configuration matching what you need
12-13-14-15-16-17-19-22-25-28

https://www.sram.com/sram/road/products/sram-pg-1050-cassette
https://www.sram.com/sram/road/products/sram-pg-1070-cassette

**If you want shimano**
Buy two Shimano 105 ten speed cassettes (well, you already have one, so you're half way there). The 12-25 version has a 16t cog and the 11-28 has the other cogs you will need. Might be able to find a used cassette that has the cog you need.

Here's the options for Shimano 105 CS-5700 series
11-25 = 11-12-13-14-15-17-19-21-23-25
11-28 = 11-12-13-14-15-17-19-21-24-28
12-25 = 12-13-14-15-16-17-19-21-23-25
12-27 = 12-13-14-15-16-17-19-21-24-27

See Shimano 105 cassette details:
http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/road/drivetrain/cassettes0/cs-5700.html

Shimano Tiagra Range has a 12-30 cassete, but it also does not have a 16t cog.
12-13-14-15-17-19-21-24-27-30T

Comment: I went with your suggestion to look for SRAM; I bought and installed the pg-1070 12-28. I like it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In theory yes. In practice there are a couple of issues:

1. Finding the cog. One, expensive, way to get one is to buy a cassette with the size you want and take it apart to get your cog – assuming that you can find one.
2. Finding the cog with the ramps to go to its partners on either side. This is a much smaller issue, the steps are as small as they get and long before Hyperglide there was shifting…

I happened to stumble on [this 16-tooth cog](http://www.fouriers-bike.com/en/pro.php?m=d&pid=346&cid=51&f=50) the other day. The overall package, a 40- or 42-tooth replacement low and a 16-tooth to clean up the steps in between, but perhaps they sell the 16-tooth by itself as a spare.

Comment: The cog I can find: this one is for Ultegra, but I suppose it should work for my 105 too (http://www.rosebikes.nl/artikel/shimano-ultegra-cs-6600-10-speed-tandwiel-met-16-tanden/aid:119171). But can I just simply put the 16 on and remove the 11?

Comment: If you have a separate lock ring (as opposed to the 11 doubling as the lock ring) then yes you can. Otherwise you'd need a 12-tooth high.